# youtube spf is not working after loading with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

On my web page, everything is okay.

My js is working very well but clicking on any page, page is loading with ajax but some function is not working for example my bootstrap carousel or my parallax.js plugin..

How do I do event management ?

I'm using [youtube spf plugin](https://github.com/youtube/spfjs)

some js example on my page

```
if (!$(".scene").length) return false;
 var q = document.getElementsByClassName("scene")[0];
 var r = new Parallax(q, {
  calibrateX: false,
  calibrateY: true,
  invertX: false,
  invertY: true,
  limitX: false,
  frictionX: .2,
  frictionY: 4,
  originX: 0,
  originY: 1
 });

$('.img-area').cycle({
      fx:     'fadeout',
      speed:   950,
      timeout: 100
  }).cycle("pause");

$(".otel-history-list").on("click",function(){


    var historyName = $(this).find(".history-current-name").text();
    var historyDateIn = $(this).find(".history-current-datein").text();
    var historyDateOut = $(this).find(".history-current-dateout").text();
    var historyKisi = $(this).find(".history-current-kisi").text();

    $(".input-form-ara input").val(historyName);
    $(".otel-giris-cikis #checkin").val(historyDateIn);
    $(".otel-giris-cikis #checkout").val(historyDateOut);
    $(".kisi-sayi-otel-sec .kisi-count").text(historyKisi);
  });
```

or something like these code

and my ajax code

```
$(function () {
    spf.init();
    NProgress.configure({ showSpinner: false });

    $(document).on('spfrequest', function (event) {
        NProgress.set(0.4);
    });

    $(document).on('spfprocess', function (event) {


        NProgress.set(0.6);
        NProgress.set(0.8);



    });



    $(document).on('spfdone', function (event) {

        NProgress.set(1.0);
        NProgress.done();



    });

    $(document).on('spfhistory', function (event) {

        NProgress.set(0.7);
        NProgress.set(0.9);
        NProgress.set(1.0);
        NProgress.done();

    });
});
```

and I'm using bootstrap,parallax.js,cycle2.js,select2 plugin

Comment: if your ajaxing your carousel, cycle2, etc you need to reinitialize this js libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've answered a similar question in the past, so I'm restating it below:

1. I'm not sure what your full code set is, but based on what you posted, I'm guessing that several of your html elements (that have JQuery event handlers attached to them) are generated and re-generated using your ajax functions-- probably several times, after your original DOM is loaded.
2. This is the most likely reason why some of your events don't fire after your Ajax codes fire. The event handlers attached to your html elements (such as divs) get "detached" when these elements are programmatically (re)generated using Ajax.
3. As such, what you would want to do is to "attach" the event handler to a higher level in the DOM tree (highest being your html) that you are sure won't get 'programmatically' regenerated, then you'd want to check if the element in question, which is inside the DOM, exists. You then run your function when this element is found.

So as an example, you have this onclick function in your code:

```
$(".otel-history-list").on("click",function(){
//your actions
  });
```

The element with the class "otel-history-list" is likely being generated or regenerated by your Ajax call after page load, and as such would get detached from your onclick event listener (See #1-#2 above).

So to rewrite your code following #3 above, you'd want to attach the event listener to something that won't be regenerated by your Ajax, then just look for the specific element inside it, which contains your class of interest:

```
$(document).on("click",".otel-history-list", function(){
    //your actions
      });
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I change function `$(document).on('click','.class or #id')` but the problem still goes on